# how to find the traffic of a roads?

Tags: android, android-emulator

i want to develop an application.

by using that application i want find the traffic of a roads.

How it is possible.

any one have idea.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Google maps on android has traffic information. Here you go.

```
mapview.setTraffic(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to find out traffic data "by using your application", here's how to do it:

1. Make the application track the user's location and movement speed via GPS and send it to a central server. Make sure you respect the user's privacy.
2. Match the locations and velocities to roads using map data (available via OpenStreetMap, for instance).
3. Get a *lot* of people to install your application
4. Enjoy your traffic data